# C++ Video Stream detect FPS

Tags: c++, opencv, video-streaming, rtsp, sdp

I try to get the correct fps of a video stream from an axis or eneo camera.

```
rtsp://192.168.0.1:554/axis-media/media.amp
```

I use [`cv::VideoCapture::get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aeb1644641842e6b104f244f049648f94) but with some cameras the result is invalid for example the result is 180000 but the correct value is 25. I have check it with wireshark and see the value in the [SDP Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Description_Protocol) is correct.

```
Media Attribute (a): framerate:25.000000
```

Which Information `cv::VideoCapture::get` read?

Comment: OpenCV doesn't detect the properties correctly for many cameras, especially if  not simple USB webcams. It's open source so you can fix it !

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV Isn't very good at this sort of thing, and likely will get it wrong a large percentage of the time. If you need this accurately immediately then I would suggest looking into other camera opening libraries.

Alternatively you could profile the stream after opening it - https://www.learnopencv.com/how-to-find-frame-rate-or-frames-per-second-fps-in-opencv-python-cpp/

Comment: Hi is another project is available that uses the sdp Information this values are correct in my tests? FFmpeg maybe?