# VideoCapture can open a video but then after some second or minute cap.read​() keeps returning false

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video-streaming, live-streaming, ip-camera

While accessing live-streaming IP camera.
VideoCapture can open a video but then after some second or minute can't read it. `cap.read​()` keeps returning false and frame is none after some time.
FPS rate of that camera is 180000. This is so high.

Python-> 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
OS- Ubuntu (18.04 or 20.04)
OpenCV - 4.4.0
opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.46

Comment: how often do you try to read more frames after your get a false return? I've seen cameras where it works again after about 200 failures.

Comment: It gives me false return until I restart the process.

Answer (score 1):

This has kinda just been an issue that everyone seems to occasionally run into while using opencv with IP cameras. You can sidestep the problem by checking if cap.read() returns false and closing and re-opening the stream if it happens (If you keep having problems after closing and re-opening then there's actually a connection issue and it's not just opencv).

Comment: It gives false return until I restart the process. I have two IP cameras over on the same place and same network. This problem is occurred only on that camera which have very high FPS rate = 180000. Second camera give me only 20 FPS rate.

Comment: I can't think of a reasonable answer as to why restarting the process would have a different effect versus closing and re-opening the VideoCapture. There might be some OpenCV black-box magic going on there that I'm not familiar with. After closing the VideoCapture, can you try sleeping for 60 seconds before re-opening it? If the only way to deal with this is to restart the process, then you can do that with the multiprocessing module.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47757112/4267439), it seems like openCV has problems with non-USB cameras. Reported fps are likely to be a default value when opencv cannot read camera properties.